# High precision calculation in R using Rmpfr

Tags: r, precision

I have to calculate `B(x+a, n-x+a)` where `B( , )` is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), `0 < a < .5`, `n = 10^8` and `x = 10^7`.

R just spits out 0 and this ruins my calculations further down the line. I tried using the `Rmpfr` package, but I get an error when using an `mpfr` object in the beta function like:

`beta(Rmpfr::mpfr(.3, 32), Rmpfr::mpfr(.4, 32))`

`Error in beta(Rmpfr::mpfr(0.3, 32), Rmpfr::mpfr(0.4, 32)) :  non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Is there a way to use this function or an extension in the `Rmpfr` package?

Comment: That’s weird, this should work: ‘Rmpfr’ overrides the `beta` function with a suitable S4 method.

Comment: seems you need `library(Rmpfr)` or `Rmpfr::beta` to call it explicitely

Comment: That is because `Rmpfr` masks several common functions when loaded explicitly.

Comment: `1 'mpfr' number of precision  53   bits 
[1] 5.1120912444844988` via Rmpfr::beta 'unmasking', which wouldn't be evident from docs, i.e. ?Rmpfr::beta
No documentation for ‘beta’ in specified packages

Comment: @user20650 Odd, in my understanding S4 shouldn’t require attaching to override functions appropriately. In fact, that’s kind of *the point*.

Comment: @carson; is it feasible to keep things on the log scale? Then can probably avoid Rmpfr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.
Define a function to compute `B(x + a, n - x + a)` and either use `lbeta` or the relation with the Gamma function to compute it. The results are different.
But first transform the input in class `"mpfr"`.

```
library(Rmpfr)

fun1 <- function(x, a, n, precBits = 128){
  x <- mpfr(x, precBits = precBits)
  y <- lbeta(x + a, n - x + a)
  exp(y)
}
fun2 <- function(x, a, n, precBits = 128){
  x <- mpfr(x, precBits = precBits)
  y <- lgamma(x + a) + lgamma(n - x + a) - lgamma(n + 2*a)
  exp(y)
}

x <- 10^7
n <- 10^8

a <- seq(0, 0.5, by = 0.1)
a[1] <- a[1] + .Machine$double.eps

y1 <- sapply(a, function(.a) fun1(x, .a, n))
y2 <- sapply(a, function(.a) fun2(x, .a, n))

identical(y1, y2)    # FALSE

for(i in seq_along(y1)){
  print(y1[[i]])
  print(y2[[i]])
  cat("------------\n")
}
#'mpfr1' 5.908917437507173802740403605476917652884e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 5.908916502709463876883575806175392305756e-14118178
#------------
#'mpfr1' 4.644427318909735435193584822408613288295e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 4.644427671609397947912541833050543093524e-14118178
#------------
#'mpfr1' 3.650534190755993708699375955051812478253e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 3.650534453825956612660829361117675142023e-14118178
#------------
#'mpfr1' 2.869331130039816933725658480797135290929e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 2.869331326837006304711880791004313346298e-14118178
#------------
#'mpfr1' 2.255303117148781009056940914963421818211e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 2.255303264892447200718169160444143102796e-14118178
#------------
#'mpfr1' 1.772675206631663936649823041615115643639e-14118178
#'mpfr1' 1.772675318013218204950148512940582629174e-14118178
#------------
```